# TextBox que recuerde el último dato registrado

Tags: c#, visual-studio

¿Hay alguna forma de hacer que un textbox recuerde el último dato escrito en él?

Tengo esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que busco es hacer que los campos que el usuario escriba se guarden incluso después de cerrar la aplicación y no tengan que estarlos escribiendo una y otra vez.
Estoy usando Visula Studio 2019 y c#

Comment: Qué has intentado?

Comment: Sí, la hay: programándolo tú. Tendrás que guardar persistente (fichero) los datos cada vez que cambien y recuperarlos al arrancar.

Comment: Se como hacerlo, pero la solución aunque es sencilla es larga en cuanto a cosas que hay que hacer, el código realmente es muy corto, debes usar una tabla o un fichero para que la información persista en tu pc y cada vez que cargues tu aplicacion se cargue este autocompletamiento.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

espero te sea de ayuda.

Puedes crear una Variable de aplicación a como te lo demuestro en la imagen.

Clic derecho sobre el nombre de tu proyecto, y dirígete a Configuración.
[image: Variables de Aplicación]

Para acceder al valor de tu variable de aplicación y asignarlo:

```
txtUser.Text = Properties.Settings.Default["NombreUsuarioSave"].ToString();
```

Para guardar algún valor a la variable, por ejemplo:

```
Properties.Settings.Default["NombreUsuarioSave"] = txtUser.Text;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Comment: Y eso me garantiza que si yo escribo en el textbox paises (solo es un ejemplo), por ej. una vez pongo Cuba, después Chile y después Argentina, se guarden todos estos paises que escribo y posteriormente cuando escribo Chi(de Chile) el textbox me ponga todos los elementos que coincidan con estas caracteres y me sugiera elementos para autocompletar el texto del textbox

Comment: @Japv, la pregunta está clara, el compañero preguntó ¿Hay alguna forma de hacer que un textbox recuerde el último dato escrito en él?. Quizás tu interpretación no es la adecuada, pienso!.

Comment: Vidal, yo te pregunte por mi, no por el otro usuario, son dos preguntas diferentes

Comment: Vidal, igual te doy mi voto pq aprendí algo q no sabia, gracias!!

Comment: @Japv lo siento mucho estimado, interpreté que te referías a lo que el compañero preguntó